# How to compile opencv with camera

Tags: ros, opencv2.2, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I try to compile my old projection with opencv. And about connecting camera, I try run [code](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages), and to run this node, I should open the camera stream. so I try rosrun [usb_cam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/usb_cam), which open the Logitech Quick-cam. But I have no idea about how to get this camera stream to link the my own node.

and this is my rxgraph:
[C:\fakepath\Screenshot.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1299485753552291.png)

and also my rostopic list as belows:

/image_topic
/image_topic_2
/image_topic_2/compressed
/image_topic_2/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/image_topic_2/compressed/parameter_updates
/image_topic_2/theora
/image_topic_2/theora/parameter_descriptions
/image_topic_2/theora/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/usb_cam/camera_info
/usb_cam/image_raw
/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed
/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/usb_cam/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/usb_cam/image_raw/theora
/usb_cam/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/usb_cam/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates

Any one can help me? and I aim to build my own opecv-projection on ROS system.

Best wishes!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9314/how-to-compile-opencv-with-camera/) by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2011-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you publish your rxgraph screenshot again with the show all topic marked? It seems that you need to remap the topic upon launching your node. More info [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Remapping%20Arguments).

something like:

```
rosrun <your_package_name> <exec_name> image:=/usb_cam/image
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-03-08**:
Yeah, i got it. I should edit  my own subscriber, and most of image processes are in subscriber file. Thanks for raphael favier and KoenBuys.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-08**:
Yongqiang, in your code, you want to subscribe to a topic named "image_topic". Your usb_cam node sends an image topic named "image". Following Koen's advice, you need to tell your node to subscribe to "image" in spite of "image_topic". Do this like this: $rosrun ros_opencv example image_topic:=image

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-03-07**:
As "http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages", should I input the command as :$rosrun ros_opencv example image:=/usb_cam/image_raw? I find that it doesn't connect between the node of "usb_cam" and the node of "image_converter", more advice?